# Man muss eventuell - ist es kein Widerspruch?

Tags: meaning

Enthält die Aussage *man muss eventuell ... etwas machen/tun* nicht einen Widerspruch in sich? *Muss* bedeutet dass etwas obligatorisch zu tun ist, *eventuell* nivelliert dieses *muss*...

Comment: Eventuell muss man die Frage mit mehr Kontext und Beispielen stellen, um bessere Antworten zu bekommen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ also `muss man` oder doch `eventuell`?

Comment: Möglicherweise, aber nicht zwingend, weil es viele auch so verstehen werden. Man könnte auch den Konjunktiv _müsste_ verwenden.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ das bezieht sich dann eher auf Usus, als auf Regel oder Logik, korrekt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Man sollte im Blick behalten, dass im Deutschen sehr oft das Präsens benutzt wird, um auf die Zukunft Bezug zu nehmen:

> Jugendliche Täter müssen eventuell zahlen ([Quelle](https://www.wa.de/hamm/uentrop-ort370525/350000-euro-schaden-lwl-schule-hamm-jugendliche-taeter-muessen-eventuell-zahlen-8451981.html))

Der Artikel spricht über das mögliche Ergebnis eines Gerichtsprozesses. Am Ende des offenen Ausganges *(eventuell)* könnte eine Zahlungsverpflichtung *(müssen)* bestehen.

Ich denke, das Beispiel macht klar, warum nicht automatisch ein Widerspruch vorliegt: Es kann sich um unterschiedliche Modalitäten handeln. Man kann diese auch auf Haupt- und Nebensatz verteilen:

> Ich halte es für möglich, dass die Jugendlichen bezahlen (werden) müssen.

Die Verpflichtung kommt vom Gesetz; die Möglichkeit ist Ausdruck meiner Erwartungen in Bezug auf die Zukunft und den Ausgang des Prozesses.

Answer (score 4):

Nein, da ist kein Widerspruch.

> Ich weiß nicht, ob wir genug Sprit haben. Das heißt, ich muss eventuell nochmal tanken.

Comment: Das Beispiel überzeugt mich nicht. Der zweite Satz enthält genau die in der Frage angesprochene Konfiguration, in der *muss eventuell* durch ein *sollte* ersetzt werden kann. Deutung 1) Wir bleiben eventuell liegen, weil der Sprit nicht reicht. Wenn ich das vermeiden will, *muss* ich tanken.Deutung 2) Ich überlege noch, ob der Sprit reicht. Wenn ich beim Losfahren ein ein schlechtes Gefühl habe, fahren wir noch bei der Tankstelle vorbei.

Comment: Wenn zu wenig Sprit da ist **muss** getankt werden. Sonst **muss nicht** getankt werden. Rausgehen in die Garage, Auto anmachen, schauen wieviel Sprit drin ist, beantwortet die Frage.

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzend zu David Vogts Antwort findet der Ausdruck oft auch in der Polemik Anwendung.

Beispiel:

*"Mann, wenn es schon stinkt, dann muss man **eventuell** auch mal selber den Müll raus bringen!"*

Erklärung:

Das eigentlich Offensichtliche *"Wenn es schon stinkt, muss man auch mal selber den Müll raus bringen (... und nicht darauf warten, dass es ein anderer tut)"*

wird hier polemisch überspitzt: *"Es es ist dringend nötig, dass der Müll raus gebracht wird, aber ich hätte eigentlich erwartet, dass du diese einfache und logische Schlussfolgerung eigenverantwortlich findest und auch umsetzt!"*

Ohne Polemik würde man wohl sagen:
"Es stinkt. Bring den Müll raus. Außerdem stört es mich, dass du das nicht schon von alleine getan hast."

Funktioniert aber im Englischen genauso.

*"Dude, if it already stinks, **maybe** one has to bring out the trash themselves sometimes!"*

---

Ebenfalls kann man es auch verwenden, um einen Vorschlag in dem Raum zu stellen, von dessen Erfolg man selber nicht ganz überzeugt ist, den man aber gerne diskutieren möchte:

*"Man muss **eventuell** Online-Marketing ausprobieren."*
-> Wir sollten überlegen, ob und wann es sich lohnen würde, das zu tun.

Hier hat das **eventuell** dann auch eine abschwächende Wirkung gegenüber:

*"Man muss Online-Marketing ausprobieren."* -> Ich weiß, dass wir es tun müssen, alles andere wäre ein Fehler!

Comment: `maybe one has to bring out`, `einer hat wegzubringen` - ist es vergleichbar mit `einer muss wegbringen` hinsichtlich Unabdingbarkeit?

Comment: Das maybe/eventuell impliziert hier eine Frage die der Angesprochene sich eigentlich selber hätte stellen müssen und deren Antwort (dem aussprechenden) auch eigentlich selbstverständlich ist. Es Verknüpft auf sarkastische Weise quasi die Aufforderung sich mal selber Gedanken zu machen was zu tun ist, mit der klaren Meinung was denn die richtige Antwort ist.

Answer (score 2):

"Man muss eventuell etwas tun" bedeutet, dass die Möglichkeit besteht, dass etwas getan werden muss. Dies ist kein Widerspruch in sich. Treten gewisse Umstände ein, muss zwingend gehandelt werden, anderenfalls erübrigt sich die Handlungsnotwendigkeit.